# Possible anticrawler

Tags: nlp, web-crawler

For an educational NLP project I need a list of all Italian words. I thought I would write a crawler that will get the words from www.wordreference.com. I use Python with the mechanize crawler framework. but when i use the code:

```
 br = mechanize.Browser()
 br.open("http://www.wordreference.com/iten/abaco")
 html = br.response().get_data()
 print html
```

I get some page from "yahoo.com". is it possible this website has an anticrawler mechanism?

Comment: Almost all (large) websites have some type of traffic monitoring to make sure it is not being crawled for data.  This prevents you from stealing their data (especially, in this case, proprietary definition data).  You might want to look and see if there is an open source dictionary listing for the Italian language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to use existing datasets, here are few examples from this [acl wiki page](http://www.aclweb.org/aclwiki/index.php?title=Resources_for_Italian):

> Corpuses:
>
> - ...
> - [Oxford Text Archive Corpus of Italian Newspapers](http://www.uni-duisburg.de/Fak2/FremdPhil/Romanistik/Personal/Burr/humcomp/)  ...
> - ...
>
> WordNets
>
> - [EuroWordNet](http://www.elda.fr/)
> - [MultiWordNet](http://multiwordnet.itc.it/english/home.php) - a multilingual lexical database in which the Italian
>     WordNet is strictly aligned with
>     Princeton WordNet 1.6 ...

Please check the full list on the acl wiki page, I think you should find an italian corpus, which let you to define italian words.